# Relative import modules from sub packages in main

Tags: python, import, pip

How does one import modules from sub packages in main, so that the proper file is imported when running program both from the local project directory and when installed via pip?

Lets look at the typical structure of the project directory.

```
spam
└── spam
    ├── egg
    │   ├── egg.py
    │   └── __init__.py
    ├── bacon
    │   ├── bacon.py
    │   └── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.py
    └── main.py
```

In the main I want to import `egg` and `bacon`.
Right now I do it with

```
from egg import egg
from bacon import bacon
```

This works as expected when I run program within the project directory with `python main.py`.
However, after installing the program with pip, and running it in any non project directory I get the information: `No module named 'egg'`.
To make it work I need:

```
from spam.egg import egg
from spam.bacon import bacon
```

However, this approach has one important drawback.
Now, if I run the program locally, the modules are imported from the pip installation, not from the local, project directory.

I have tried relative imports like:

```
from .egg import egg
```

or

```
from ..egg import egg
```

but they return `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`.

I have checked few projects on GitHub to see how people do this and it turned out all of them use the `from spam.egg import egg` approach.
I doubt this is correct approach.
If one has some tests run by the shell within the project, they might pass or fail falsely, because the modules from the pip installation are being used, not the local ones.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```py
$ head *.py */*.py
==> main.py <==
import egg,bacon
egg.egg_func()
bacon.bacon_func()


==> bacon/bacon.py <==
def bacon_func():
 print("im a bacon")


==> bacon/__init__.py <==
from .bacon import bacon_func


==> egg/egg.py <==
def egg_func():
 print("im an egg")


==> egg/__init__.py <==
from .egg import egg_func
```

and

```sh
$ tree
.
├── bacon
│   ├── bacon.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── __pycache__
│       ├── bacon.cpython-38.pyc
│       └── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
├── egg
│   ├── egg.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── __pycache__
│       ├── egg.cpython-38.pyc
│       └── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
└── main.py

4 directories, 9 files
```

the output is:

```
$ python3 main.py 
im an egg
im a bacon
```

Comment: You are missing the point. You have replaced importing the modules with importing the packages. And the point is how to point to the packages relatively.

Comment: @AlBundy, you mean, you want to use `import spam.egg.egg_func` outside of spam?

Comment: No, I mean that I do not want to replace module importing with package importing. In other words, I want `__init__.py` files to be empty. Nevertheless, your approach still has the same problem I am facing.

Comment: I cant understand your question Clearly. U want to have `egg`, `bacon`, `spam` as three different modules?

Comment: Yes, and `egg` is a module of `egg` sub package and `bacon` is a module of `bacon` sub package.